# Dump all schemas and triggers and import them into another Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, testing, timesten

Is there anyway to grab the schemas and triggers from an oracle database and import them into another oracle database(an Oracle TimesTen inmemory db to be precise)? I'm trying to setup an in memory database for testing purposes and need to replicate the production schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Oracle Data Pump. [Oracle docs are here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm). Tim Hall has a [writeup here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php). You might consider the Network Import feature too, [as described here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump#Network_import).